# Is the model theory consistent/satisfiable?

Tags: model-theory

Edit: Maybe I wasn't clear my **question** is: If the model theory is expressible in a formal language is it a formal theory? If not why?
If the theory of the models is not expressible in a formal language is not problematic for the theory models itself?

Maybe it is a strange question. The Theory of models is a formal theory of some languages $L$ of the first order? If Yes which one? If yes there is a $L$-structure that satisfies this language or in other words, is the theory of models consistent/satisfiable? Does it even make sense to ask these questions? It is a self-reference? If it is self-reference what guarantees us that the theory of modules is something "true"?
If the Theory of models is not a formal theory of some languages $L$ it is not problematic to define concepts as theory, models, consistency, satisfiability, etc. with an idea that is not a formal "somethings"?

Comment: How is the theory of models a formal theory? Can you explain this?

Comment: This is exactly what I asked :)

Comment: Model theory is mathematics, so can be formalized in the same ways any piece of mathematics can be formalized, e.g. in set theory, type theory or what-have-you. There’s no magical difference just cause we’re talking *about* logic-related things like formulas rather than elliptic curves.

Comment: So it is a formal theory? Hence we can ask if it is a consistent/satisfiable theory. It is? There is a $L$-structure for which the interpretation of a theory written in a formal language is the model theory?

Comment: The term model theory does not refer to a particular formal theory, rather it describes an area of mathematics, just like, say, the terms analytic number theory and algebraic geometry. However, the definitions and results in any of these areas can be formalized in ZFC set theory (or in some other such meta-theory).